# Cross-Reference to Heading Text of Heading generates Error! Reference source not found. after source text is updated

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, bookmarks, cross-reference

**TL;DR:** Cross-References to the Heading Text of a Heading-styled paragraph are incredibly fragile and don't survive in the real world where users edit text. Terrible workaround: Make all edits to the non-last word in the heading-styled paragraph. How can we simply and reliably cross-reference heading text in an environment where users are not Word experts?

Hi. This one is a doozy from a user-experience perspective, because it's really hard to justify this behaviour. Users of this template must be able to create cross-references to procedure titles within the document. Procedure titles are Heading 7. Headings are not (and will not be) numbered in this template.

Initial condition:
[image]

The Task column will be numbers representing the order of operations. The Procedure column will contain the Procedure Title. You can guess what the Page column is for.

Expected workflow: User places cursor in the Procedure row > References > Cross-reference > Reference type=Heading > For which heading=Procedure Title > Insert reference to=Heading Text; repeat for Insert reference to=Page number.
[image]

Results are exactly as expected:
[image]

Here's where it goes all wrong. User then changes the text of Procedure Title (the paragraph mark is untouched) and updates the cross-reference:
[image]

We get Error! Reference source not found. Arrgh.

Similar problems have been resolved by making the cross-reference to Reference type=Numbered Item/Insert reference to=Paragraph text. However, these headings will not be numbered, so that's not an option.
[image]

Trial, error, and XML have revealed an unexpected behaviour. The cross-reference to Heading Text appears to be not to the heading text, but to the range of the heading text that was present when the bookmark was initially created. If it's changed in any way other than something ridiculously specific for the real world, the range does not update and the bookmark will fail.

Here's the XML of the freshly-inserted cross-references:
[image]

And here's the XML of the cross-reference targets, wrapped with bookmarkStart and bookmarkEnd:
[image]

Everything is wonderful.

Now we update the Procedure Title to New Text and update the references. (For sake of reducing the screen cap volume, I'm only updating and screen capping the reference to Heading Text. But it's the same basic problem for the reference to Page Number even though the error text is now inexplicably worded Error! Bookmark not defined..)
[image]

[image]

[image]

This is stupid. Everything that identifies this range as a bookmark is gone. A user expects to be able to update text and references to the text should not be destroyed – or in this case, the reference anchors should not be destroyed. Those bookmarkStart and bookmarkEnd tags surround the range, but edits to the range text level destroy their surroundings. Whatever technical justification there may be for this is irrelevant* because the user experience is utterly terrible.

*Example: When editing existing text, a new range is created to hold the edits and an rsidR identifies the individual edit range for change tracking and doc merging purposes. But the bookmarkStart and bookmarkEnd tags do not surround the net range, which is what a user would expect – they remain statically wrapping the remnants of the original range.

I found a circumstance where this works as one might expect! (the "something ridiculously specific" I mentioned an hour ago). If the user edits or replaces existing non-last words, it works. It also works when edits are prepended to the last word. (See green highlights.) BUT! If changes are appended to the last word, the last word is replaced, or new text is added after the last word, it falls outside the range and fails. If the text is entirely replaced (as above), the entire range is replaced. The bookmarkStart and bookmarkEnd do NOT react well to changing real-world usage as a normal human being would expect.
[image]

So… what's the simple and reliable answer to cross-referencing heading text? Do I tell users to re-create the cross-reference every time they update the heading text? They (almost) might as well not make cross-references then.

BTW thanks for listening to me rant. :-)

PS: A TOC isn't the answer. The order in which each Procedure Title is listed in the document isn't necessarily the order in which they'll be listed in the table. The tasks involved in changing a car's tire are identical; the order of the tasks determines whether you're taking the tire off or putting it on.

Cross-posted to: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2010/cross-reference-to-heading-text-of-heading/219ea22a-12de-4df8-b76e-a715ddd6eccb?tm=1556143226993

Similar to: [Microsoft word - How to prevent/fix cross-reference Error! Reference source not found](https://superuser.com/questions/1201041/microsoft-word-how-to-prevent-fix-cross-reference-error-reference-source-not/1201057)

Answer (score 1):

Responding here, because this page seems to come up in google if you search for certain bookmark and cross-reference problems, specifically the "last character gets lost when I edit bookmarks" issue. I found a slightly ugly but usable workaround that may work in certain projects.

In my case, the project is: I have user-editable text on a label, an 8-digit number. Whatever number they type, I want to be duplicated as a barcode below the number.

To make this work, I highlighted the user-editable text, inserted a bookmark... then typed out the barcode (using a font like Free3of9), highlighted it, and created a cross reference to the 8-digit number. So the barcode number should now match whatever the user types.

(aside: To preserve the barcode font, you can right click the cross reference, edit field, go to field code at the bottom left, and then add the switches \h * charformat)

Anyway, to address the main problem: If a user highlights the last digit of the number and retypes it, the bookmark shortens by 1 digit, because you don't really "replace" the number, you technically delete it for a split second, then add a new number, which is always inserted AFTER the end of the bookmark.

To prevent this, I add a special character at the end of the number. The special character is included in the bookmark. I think it's unicode 200B, zero-width space. you can copy it on emptycharacter.com and then paste it into word. It's invisible, but you may see some things slightly shift vertically. This special character works because it meets several needs:

• It's invisible and zero width, so even though the barcode text duplicates it, the barcode remains scannable.
• If other barcode stuff needs to appear after the editable number, it won't be affected.
• If you double click the number, the empty character isn't automatically included, so you can replace the number without screwing up the bookmark.
• If you need to update just the last digit or two, and highlight them, the hidden character won't be automatically highlighted, (maybe it will if you have that word option set, where partially selecting a word automatically grabs the entire word. But I disable that option)

Anyway, it solved the problem for me, I can edit the bookmark without losing the last character, and to the end user, the fix is invisible.

Comment: This sounds like it would work well in any situation where the "input field" can be pre-inserted by the template designer, whether as part of the template text or by a user-executed macro.

Comment: I found a better fix for this, later. But it may not be suitable for everyone. I just did the work in Excel. You can still do formatting to fonts etc., and use Page Layout view to make sure it fits on letter size or whatever. Then, to get a reference that updates every time someone changes the contents of a cell (let's say B3), just put in this formula in the cell that needs to automatically update: =B3

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean by embedding an Excel worksheet into the document? That may be suitable for folks whose tables are able to fit on one page. It sounds like the Excel table is self-contained and requires manual updates to keep it up-to-date with the Word content? If the heading text or page number changes, wouldn't one need to manually open and update the embedded Excel object? And possibly reformat the page layout? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Neman Ah sorry, I was unclear. I am skipping MS Word entirely, and using Excel. Although Excel is not a designer's dream, you can format the fonts, colors, etc. until you have a document that looks 'word-like', but has properly updating references. There's a lot of crossover between the apps, Excel can do images and arbitrarily-placed text boxes, clipart, text effects, etc. Maybe wouldn't work for a lot of cases, but it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Doug Robbins and Jay Freedman answered [at my cross-post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2010/cross-reference-to-heading-text-of-heading/219ea22a-12de-4df8-b76e-a715ddd6eccb) and both confirmed there is no user-friendly solution. There are two options:

1. Recreate the cross-reference after editing the heading text.
2. Edit the heading text up to, but NOT including the last character. Confirm the cross-reference, then delete the last character using the Delete key (not Backspace) in order to preserve the bookmarkStart and bookmarkEnd assigned to that range.

Geez...